# Dokku WordPress max upload filesize

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, nginx, dokku

I want to run WordPress 4.7 with nginx on Dokku 0.72, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and the only problem I have is the maximum upload filesize (2MB) that I can't increase.

My Procfile is the following:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C app.conf public/
```

I tried to set **client_max_body_size** in the app.conf and I added a custom conf in /home/dokku/../nginx.conf.d as described in [Dokku docs](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku~v0.7.2/configuration/nginx/#customizing-via-configuration-files-included-by-the-default-tem).

Also the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in wp-config did not help.

And I tried to set a custom .user.ini described in [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings).

Nothing works and I have no idea what to do now.

app.conf:

```
index index.php;

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
  access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

client_max_body_size 50M;
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "../..",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Marvin Engelmann",
            "email": ".."
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "7.0.14"
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I found a solution:

I added a custom php.ini parameter in Procfile like:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf -i php.ini public/
```

and added a custom php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
mkdir /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/
echo 'client_max_body_size 50M;' > /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
```

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEM:**

My upload_max_filesize is limited to 2M when i run

```
dokku run appName php -ini | grep upload_max_filesize
```

**SOLUTION:**

1. create a .user.ini file exactly where your index.php is, if you are
   using laravel, your index.php will be inside public folder
2. paste this code inside it then commit and push your code `upload_max_filesize = 512M post_max_size = 512M`

Comment: This is almost the same of what OP had founded.